# RVM Upgrade Warning Files containing `PATH=` with no `$PATH` inside

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rvm

I am curious as to how to fix the path of my files. I was given the WARNING message from `rvm get stable --autolibs=enable` and am not sure how to approach the warning.

Here is the message:

```
Upgrade Notes:

/Users/user/.bash_profile:1:export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin:/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/bin:/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/user/.rvm/bin:/Users/user/mongodb/bin

  * WARNING: Above files contains `PATH=` with no `$PATH` inside, this can break RVM,
    for details check https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/1351#issuecomment-10939525
    to avoid this warning append #PATH.
```

I'm really curious to see if this is part of the reason why I am seeing so many gem installation issues.

How do I fix this path and check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your .bash_profile. Change the line

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin:/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/bin:/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/user/.rvm/bin:/Users/user/mongodb/bin
```

to

```
export PATH="/usr/local/mysql/bin:/Users/user/mongodb/bin:$PATH"
```

. Note what I did:

1. I took out all the `/Users/user/.rvm/…` directories; you probably want RVM to manage those itself.
2. I took out `/usr/local/bin`, `/usr/local/sbin`, `/usr/bin`, `/bin`, `/usr/sbin`, and `/sbin`; those are almost certainly already on the PATH that the shell starts with (before running .bash_profile). It's possible `/usr/sbin` and `/sbin` are *not* already there; if so, you might want to add them in .bash_profile.
3. I put double quotes around it in case any part of it has spaces (which would be a bad idea, but it's a good idea to safeguard against it just in case).
4. I put `:$PATH` at the end -- its absence is what RVM was complaining about. This makes it so `/usr/local/mysql/bin` and `/Users/user/mongodb/bin` are added to the PATH that's supplied to the shell, rather than replacing it. And since the `:$PATH` part is at the very end, bash will search your custom PATH entries first and default system locations last.